# To find Custom objects inside apex

Tags: apex, describesobject, schema, describesobjectresult

I want to check whether a given object is standard or custom.
At present I have a method which identifies custom objects but that is taking too much CPU time, which leads to salesforce exception.

```
public static Boolean getAllCustomSObjects(String objectname)
{Boolean customobject;
List<String> sObjectList = new List<String>();
for(Schema.SObjectType objTyp : Schema.getGlobalDescribe().Values())
{
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult describeSObjectResultObj = objTyp.getDescribe();
    if(describeSObjectResultObj.isCustom())
    { 
        String name = objTyp.getDescribe().getName();
        // Exclude all the unwanted Sobjects e.g. History, Share etc..
   /*     if(!name.containsignorecase('history') && !name.containsignorecase('tag')&&
         !name.containsignorecase('share') && !name.containsignorecase('feed'))
        {
            SobjectList.add(name);
        } */
        if(name.contains(objectname))
        {customobject=true;
        System.debug('Custom object found');
        }
        else
        {
         customobject=false;
         System.debug('Custom object not found');
        }
    }
}
system.debug('SObjectList****' + SObjectList);
return customobject;
}
```

Instead of fetching all the custom object names and checking whether the the given object name is a custom object, I want to check the object directly. I tried to modify the line

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult describeSObjectResultObj = objTyp.getDescribe();
```

and to give the object name as parameter for DescribeSObjectResult but it was throwing error.Do anyone help in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a for loop here. You can do something like

```
public static Boolean checkObjectType(String objectname) {
    SObjectType objToken = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(ObjectNameval);
    if(objToken  != null && objToken.getDescribe().isCustom())
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

This method will return true if it is custom object or false if it is not. Also one major difference is All custom objects end with `__c` with Standard object don't have these suffix.

Comment: Your code is returning false all time.

Comment: @Aruna: try using `return false;` inside `else` like 
`else return false;`. It shouldn't make any difference with the existing code but just for the safe side.

Comment: I tried that too, not working

Answer (score 0):

you can use SObjectType class methods to find out.
method mentioned by @Tushar gives me TRUE if it is custom object.

```
public static Boolean checkObjectType(String objectname) {
   SObjectType objToken = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectname);
   if(objToken  != null && objToken.getDescribe().isCustom()) {
     return true;
   } else {
     return false;
   }
}
```

pass the objectname as a String and it will return TRUE if is a custom object.

And the easiest way is to use check the suffix '__c' at the end of name. 
use String class method 
`String s = 'Custom_object__c';
System.assert(s.endsWith('__c'));`

[String Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm)

[SObjectType Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_SObjectType.htm)

Comment: May be you are checking wrong. Plz try with both standard and custom objects.

Comment: for me its working.
`SObjectType objToken = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Account');
System.debug('OBJ ' + objToken.getDescribe().isCustom());` is returning **FALSE** and
`SObjectType objToken = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Custom_Object__c');
System.debug('OBJ ' + objToken.getDescribe().isCustom());` is returning **TRUE**

Comment: if still not working use string method and check '__c' at the end.

Comment: When used in SOQL both standard and custom objects will get the suffix '__r'. ex: CarSet__r.CarSetDate__c,  CarSet__r.Order__r.EffectiveDate. When I try to give the objects inside the code you gave its returning false all time.

Comment: For standard objects I want to remove the suffix '__r' and for custom objects I want to replace the suffix '__r' to '__c'. I hope you'll understand my point now

Answer (score 0):

@Tushar, Thanks your code was working. Since I was trying to find the custom objects from SOQL a suffix'__r' will be appended to all the objects with relationships.That's why first I got error but then  I did small change to the code. ie.I replaced the suffix of objects from '__r' to '__c'. After doing this the code worked fine.

```
public static String checkObjectType(String objectname) {
String obj=objectname.replace('__r','__c');
SObjectType objToken = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(obj);
if(objToken  != null && objToken.getDescribe().isCustom()) {
 return 'true';
} else {
 return 'false';
}
}
```